# How can I convert one date and time from two colums?

Tags: matlab, date, time, cells

Im trying to convert the first two columns of a cell into a Matlab time. First column {1,1} is the date in **YYYY-MM-DD** format and the second is the time in **HH:MM** format.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? My code:

```
    file = 'D:\Beach Erosion and Recovery\Bournemouth\Bournemouth Tidal 
    Data\tidal_data_jtide.txt'
    fileID = fopen(file);
    LT_celldata = textscan(fileID,'%D%D%D%D%d%[^\n\r]','delimiter',',');
    formattime = 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'
    date = LT_celldata{1,1};
    time = LT_celldata{1,2};
    date_time = datenum('date','time'); code
```

Screenshot below is `LT_celldata{1,1}` :

[image]

Comment: Try `date = datetime(LT_celldata{:,1},'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd')` and `time = datetime(LT_celldata{:,2},'InputFormat','HH:mm','Format','HH:mm')` Do you want to combine them or...?

Comment: Yeah I'd like to combine them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine  variables `date` and `time` with the following code:

```
date = datetime(LT_celldata{1,1},'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd');
time = datetime(LT_celldata{1,2},'InputFormat','HH:mm:ss','Format','HH:mm:ss');

myDatetime = datetime(date + timeofday(time),'Format','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

The code uses *timeofday* function to combine date and time information from the two different variables. You may find more information and examples at [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/combine-date-and-time-from-separate-variables.html) documentation page.